# virtualenv not running after install

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

I have

```
$ which virtualenv
$
```

and

```
$ virtualenv --version
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I have tried to add virtualenv to my PATH, but I don't really know what I'm doing. Here is the PATH

```
$PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin/virtualenv:/usr/local/bin/virtualenv/virtualenv.py
```

As you might expect, the problem persists.

What exactly do I need to do to fix this?

I am pretty sure I need to add virtualenv to PATH somehow, but what is "virtualenv" ?

Does that mean the .py file, or if there are multiple copies, where should I be looking? If no one can provide a solution to this problem, as least a clarification of what the problem is for me would help with troubleshooting.

I used

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

to install, which yielded

```
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg
```

Thanks.

Comment: How and where did you install virtualenv?

Comment: I used sudo easy_install virtualenv, I'm not sure where exactly that installed it

Comment: in your `PATH`, note the entity `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv/virtualenv.py`.  Perhaps do an `ls -l` on that and see what's inside (that may actually be the executable).

Comment: OK, the last two paths I added manually by the way

Comment: @metatoaster it is executable but when run I get $ /usr/local/bin/virtualenv/virtualenv.py --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv/virtualenv.py: Permission denied

Comment: Try `python /usr/local/bin/virtualenv/virtualenv.py`

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot the python precursor. It works now. Why is that I can't just call virtualenv --version though if it is in the PATH?

Comment: I don't know how OS X (or the version of python it ships with) handles paths or entry point creation. Basically it didn't create the executable `virtualenv` in any of the default `PATH`,  or that your current shell session couldn't see the newly created `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` because it wasn't there before the one that is being executed.

Comment: Open the virtualenv.py file. What does the first line (shabang line) of the file say? Also what do you get when you do a 'which python'?

Comment: 'which python' gives me '/usr/local/bin/python', and the first line of the file is '#!/usr/bin/env python'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, installing `virtualenv` will create a thin wrapper script somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`.  I don't know why yours didn't; but it's so simple that you can copy/paste it manually to `$HOME/bin/virtualenv` or wherever.  (You don't seem to have `$HOME/bin` in your `PATH` so you'd have to add that then, or put it somewhere like `/usr/local/bin` if you have the permissions and feel that you know what you are doing ... but I'm getting the feeling you should not.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import virtualenv
virtualenv.main()
```

Alternatively, put something like `alias virtualenv='python /that/long/path/to/virtualenv.py'` in your `.bash_profile` or similar.

These are simple workarounds; figuring out after the fact why the installation failed without more details about your system (including the output from `easy_install` when you ran it) is probably too complex for a Stack Overflow question.

Incidentally, the last component of your `PATH` is wrong.  The `PATH` variable is a colon-separated list of *directories*; adding an individual file to the `PATH` will not work.  In theory, you could change it so that the parent directory is on the path, and always use `virtualenv.py` instead of just `virtualenv`, but I don't think that's a proper fix (and actually I'm not sure whether it will work.  Looks like it will if you have a version which is similar to mine, but what if you don't?).